# updating cuda results in zesty repository missing

Tags: cuda, repository, apt-get

When executing:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following error:

```
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local  Release [574 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-0-local  Release [574 B]
Ign:3 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                                                            
Ign:6 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease                                                                                                             
Ign:7 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                                                                        
Err:9 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release                                                                                                                      
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err:10 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release                                                                           
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Err:11 http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release                             
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8001::11 80]
Hit:12 http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable InRelease                                
Ign:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease        
Err:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::16 80]
Hit:15 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Hit:16 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

From what I can tell is that the zesty repository which contained my cuda package has been removed? Is there anyway how I ca, replace this or if it'll come back?

Comment: This question is off-topic for [SO]. You would be better served asking somewhere else like https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 17.04 zesty's end-of-life date was 2018-01-13. It is no longer supported: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

You could use `old-releases.ubuntu.com`, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades